# Matching 3 lines following a term using GREP

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, grep

Here is a sample of the text.

> NEW! Certificate in Office Operations (3 parts)
>   Office Operations
>   Cyber Security for Managers
>   Embracing Sustainability in the Workplace
>   Intro to 3D Printing
>   Intro to Maker Tech: The New Shop Class

I need to be able to match the three lines the follow any line containing the string "(3 parts)"

My thought would be to try a positive look-behind like this:

```
(?<=\(3 parts\)$)^.*$
```

but it doesn't match anything.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on StackOverflow as it's really about GREP more than graphic design. And it seems some people on SO *love* GREP puzzles. (which is a good thing :)

Comment: Does indesign's flavor of GREP allow for multi-line searches? The most basic paragraph is a line break, so GREP paragraph styles presumably stop looking at newline. (I think search-replace GREP can, but not GREP styles)

Comment: I started in StackOverFlow and they were able to give me stuff that would work in other flavors of GREP but not in Indesign so I thought that i would try over here in Graphic Design.

I am fairly new to GREP so I wasn't sure if Indesign could handle it. I was hoping that i could do it with a grep style but if i have to to do it through find and replace that would still be better than doing it all manually. I just can't figure out how to tell it what to look for.

Comment: GREP is confusing enough...Adobe using their own version sounds even worse. Good luck! :)

Comment: GREP *Styles* do not match multiple paragraphs. They stop looking beyond paragraph boundaries. It should work in a regular (GREP) Find and Change (except you probably should not use `$` but `\r`).

Comment: If you are able to match the (3 parts), I seem to recall there is a way to specify how styles are supposed to cascade down but I haven't used this in years. I think it's not automatic but still more efficient (i.e. than typing a shortcut or something along those lines)

Answer (score 4):

This is the GREP selecting only the following three paragraphs after the "...(3 parts)" sentence:

```
(?<=\(3 parts\)\r)(.+\r){3}
```

[image]

Search all the characters and the following `.+` until the end of the paragraph `\r` repeated three times `{3}` preceded by `(?<=...)` (3 parts) and the end of the paragraph `\(3 parts\)\r`. With this you make sure the "...(3 parts)" sentence and its *end of paragraph* invisible character are not included in the search.

Answer (score 0):

if you're doing this in indesign, are you able to change the '3 parts' text to something different? like '!!' for example, as you can hide simple characters like these using a character style.

I used 2 GREP styles in 1 paragraph style.
Grep 1: apply [wanted style] to .+!!
Grep 2: apply [hide style] to !!

[Hide style] is a character style where the size is 1pt, and horizontal and vertical scale are 1%

this should highlight all text before the '!!' and hide the '!!' for you too